# "Out of ink" notification cannot be dismissed

Tags: release-freya, notifications, printer

My printer is running low on color ink but I don't need to print in color right now. Still, whenever I print anything, I get a "Out of ink" notification that I can't dismiss without restarting elementary OS.

Here is a screenshot of that problem:
[image]

How can I disable that particular notification?

Comment: Guys, I think we're being a little over zealous here with the close votes (unless you all see something I don't).

Comment: This is a notification on Freya? Could you try posting a screenshot?

Comment: I have the same issue on Freya .3

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me:
Switch to next desktop (windows key + right arrow)
Now you can click the "X" to dismiss the notification

Return to your daily business

Comment: Dosen't work for me. I have a birdie notification that's stuck. Moving over to a new desktop and clicking close button on the notification, does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable notifications for your printer under:
**System Settings** -> **Notifications**

For me there are two entries **Printer** and **System Config Printer Notification**.

Maybe just toggle them off/on helps to dismiss the notification.

Comment: I cannot check this right now since I am on vacation. But I think I tried that and it didn't work.